# PPTP VPN Server can't be accessed over internet

Tags: networking, vpn

We have an office with 2 networks:

- Network A ip address 192.168.1.0/24 which have the ISP router (R1) with an address of 192.168.1.1 and
- Network B with ip address of 192.168.5.0/24 which has a router (R2) with an address of 192.168.5.1 and wan port configured with 192.168.1.254 for network B to access the internet.

On network B, there is a VPN server that we would like to access over the Internet. I have configured port forwarding in both routers but it doesn't seem to work.
After some investigation I found that network A devices can't ping network B devices but devices in B can ping devices in A pings normally